# Snowflake Using Streams to Track Updates/Deletes to a Table

Tags: sql, change-tracking, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am having trouble understanding how Streams work in terms of tracking changes. I would like to create a history table that tracks every `UPDATE` and `DELETE` to a table, but I am finding I do not understand how this works.

If I have table `Table1` with a Stream:

```
 CREATE TABLE Table1
 (
   XID INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,
   FIELD1 INT,
   FIELD2 STRING,
   DATECREATED TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP::TIMESTAMP
 );

 CREATE STREAM Table1_History ON TABLE Table1;
```

If I insert data:

```
INSERT INTO Table1 (FIELD1,FIELD2)
VALUES
(101,'String1'),
(102,'String2')
;
```

Then run:

```
SELECT * FROM Table1_History;
```

It returns the following:

```
XID FIELD1  FIELD2  DATECREATED METADATA$ACTION METADATA$ISUPDATE   METADATA$ROW_ID
1   101 String1 2020-08-13 06:52:34.402 INSERT  FALSE   23bc7a4d83522484f4d7e36edf84b4c7986dfa9b
2   102 String2 2020-08-13 06:52:34.402 INSERT  FALSE   5b5e429cf3a174303b2f2192b5d602ed9dedd865
```

So far so good.

But if I run:

```
UPDATE Table1 SET FIELD1 = 1001 WHERE XID = 1;
```

Then select from `Table1_History`, I get:

```
SELECT * FROM Table1_History;

XID FIELD1  FIELD2  DATECREATED METADATA$ACTION METADATA$ISUPDATE   METADATA$ROW_ID
1   1001    String1 2020-08-13 06:52:34.402 INSERT  FALSE   23bc7a4d83522484f4d7e36edf84b4c7986dfa9b
2   102 String2 2020-08-13 06:52:34.402 INSERT  FALSE   5b5e429cf3a174303b2f2192b5d602ed9dedd865
```

The `METADATA$ACTION` is still `INSERT`, and the `FIELD1` value is now stored in the stream as `1001`. There is no longer any record I can see that the row used to have a value of `101` and that it was updated.

If I run the following:

```
DELETE FROM Table1 WHERE XID = 2;
```

The stream now returns:

```
SELECT * FROM Table1_History;

XID FIELD1  FIELD2  DATECREATED METADATA$ACTION METADATA$ISUPDATE   METADATA$ROW_ID
1   1001    String1 2020-08-13 06:52:34.402 INSERT  FALSE   23bc7a4d83522484f4d7e36edf84b4c7986dfa9b
```

There is now 0 records I can see on the stream of the second row ever being in the database.

I dont get the point of the Stream table for tracking `UPDATES/DELETES`. Is this not the use of streams?

I tried following this: [Snowflake Streams Made Simple](https://snowflake.pavlik.us/index.php/2020/01/12/snowflake-streams-made-simple/), but I still dont understand.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To quote the Snowflake documentation:
"A stream stores the *current* transactional version of a table and is the appropriate source of CDC records in most scenarios."

Have a look at this example in the Snowflake documentation: https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/streams.html#example-1

My understanding is that a stream will only hold the current version of a record until you advance the offset. So if you insert a record and then update it, before advancing the offset, then it will show a single insert but the fields will hold the latest values.

If you then advance the offset and update or delete the record then those events will show in the stream - though if you updated and then deleted the same record (before advancing the offset) the stream would just show the delete, as that's the last position for that record.

**UPDATE 1**
It sounds like you are trying to implement audit tracking for every change made to a record in a table - this is not what Streams are designed to do and I don't think you would be able to implement a solution, using Streams, that guaranteed to log every change.

If you read the Streams documentation it states "The stream can provide the set of changes from the current offset to the current transactional time of the source table (i.e. the current version of the table). The stream maintains only the delta of the changes; if multiple DML statements change a row, the stream contains only the latest action taken on that row."

CDC is a terminology specifically related to loading data warehouses and is never meant as a generic term for capturing every change made to a record.

If you want to create a genuine auditing capability in Snowflake then I'm afraid I don't know if that is possible. The time travel feature shows that Snowflake retains all the changes made to a record (within the retention period) but I'm not aware of any way of accessing just these changes; I think you can only access the history of a record at points in time and you have no way of knowing at what times any changes were made

**UPDATE 2**
Just realised that Snowflake allows Change Tracking on a table without necessarily using Streams. This is probably a better solution if you want to capture all changes to a table, not just the latest version. The functionality is documented here:
https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/constructs/changes.html

Comment: I am starting to understand that now, but that means I must `INSERT` the records from `Table1_History` into another table to move forward the offset before running an `UPDATE/DELETE`. That means you need two tables to track changes: the stream and then the stream target to dump the stream records after each process that could potentially affect the original table. I guess I will create two tables and one stream: `Table1`, `Table1_History`, and `Table1_Stream` where the History table actually stores all changes permanently. Would you agree that is the necessary design?

Comment: I saw your edits and will mark your answer as correct, however I don't agree that "audit tracking is impossible". Audit tracking just requires that you dump the stream after every DML changing operation. For a managed Table you can easily just load the stream records into another table. In a standard MS `SQL` database you would do this operation with a `TRIGGER` on `UPDATE/DELETE`. Since Snowflake doesn't support Triggers you just have to run the `INSERT` into the History table as part of all DML operations. I will post the operation in a new response.

Answer (score 0):

Alright so as @NickW stated the streams table is more about tracking changes between offsets. This means I can still do what I want to do, but it will require an explicit `INSERT` into a History table between `DML` operations.

First create the main Table, the stream, and the History table:

```
CREATE TABLE Table1
(
   XID INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,
   FIELD1 INT,
   FIELD2 STRING,
   DATECREATED TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP::TIMESTAMP
);

CREATE STREAM Table1_Stream ON TABLE Table1;

CREATE TABLE Table1_History
(
   UID INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,
   XID INT,
   FIELD1 INT,
   FIELD2 STRING,
   DATECREATED TIMESTAMP,
   METADATA$ACTION STRING,   --METADATA Column from Stream
   METADATA$ISUPDATE STRING, --METADATA Column from Stream
   DATEINSERTED TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP::TIMESTAMP
);
```

Then `INSERT` records:

```
INSERT INTO Table1 (FIELD1,FIELD2)
VALUES
(101,'String1'),
(102,'String2')
;
```

The Stream Table now reads:

```
SELECT * FROM Table1_Stream;

XID FIELD1  FIELD2  DATECREATED METADATA$ACTION METADATA$ISUPDATE   METADATA$ROW_ID
1   101    String1 2020-08-13 06:52:34.402 INSERT  FALSE   23bc7a4d83522484f4d7e36edf84b4c7986dfa9b
2   102 String2 2020-08-13 06:52:34.402 INSERT  FALSE   5b5e429cf3a174303b2f2192b5d602ed9dedd865
```

Then do an `INSERT` from the Streams table to the History table:

```
INSERT INTO Table1_History(XID,FIELD1,FIELD2,DATECREATED,
                           METADATA$ACTION,METADATA$ISUPDATE)
SELECT XID,FIELD1,FIELD2,DATECREATED,
       METADATA$ACTION,UPPER(METADATA$ISUPDATE)
FROM Table1_Stream
WHERE METADATA$ACTION <> 'INSERT'
OR METADATA$ISUPDATE = 'TRUE'
```

Note the `WHERE` clause which eliminates `INSERT` only records unless it is part of an `UPDATE`, which `DELETEs` then `INSERTs` a record.

Now, even though the stream records were not actually inserted into the history table because of the `WHERE` clause, if you query the Stream you get NULL:

```
SELECT * FROM Table1_Stream;

XID FIELD1  FIELD2  DATECREATED METADATA$ACTION METADATA$ISUPDATE   METADATA$ROW_ID
```

Now if you do an `UPDATE` the stream will show it:

```
UPDATE Table1 SET FIELD1 = 1001 WHERE XID = 1;

SELECT * FROM Table1_Stream;

XID FIELD1  FIELD2  DATECREATED METADATA$ACTION METADATA$ISUPDATE   METADATA$ROW_ID
1   1001    String1 2020-08-14 09:11:20.173 INSERT  TRUE    93256f240f338581cc4781c2e79a28075e1b66d7
1   101 String1 2020-08-14 09:11:20.173 DELETE  TRUE    93256f240f338581cc4781c2e79a28075e1b66d7
```

Now run the insert:

```
INSERT INTO Table1_History(XID,FIELD1,FIELD2,DATECREATED,
                           METADATA$ACTION,METADATA$ISUPDATE)
SELECT XID,FIELD1,FIELD2,DATECREATED,
       METADATA$ACTION,UPPER(METADATA$ISUPDATE)
FROM Table1_Stream
WHERE METADATA$ACTION <> 'INSERT'
OR METADATA$ISUPDATE = 'TRUE'

SELECT * FROM Table1_History;

UID XID FIELD1  FIELD2  DATECREATED METADATA$ACTION METADATA$ISUPDATE   DATEINSERTED
1   1   1001    String1 2020-08-14 09:11:20.173 INSERT  TRUE    2020-08-14 09:13:41.474
2   1   101 String1 2020-08-14 09:11:20.173 DELETE  TRUE    2020-08-14 09:13:41.474
```

And the Stream is NULL again:

```
SELECT * FROM Table1_Stream;

XID FIELD1  FIELD2  DATECREATED METADATA$ACTION METADATA$ISUPDATE   METADATA$ROW_ID
```

If you run a `DELETE`, the change is again reflected in the Stream:

```
DELETE FROM Table1 WHERE XID = 2

SELECT * FROM Table1_Stream;

XID FIELD1  FIELD2  DATECREATED METADATA$ACTION METADATA$ISUPDATE   METADATA$ROW_ID
2   102 String2 2020-08-14 09:11:20.173 DELETE  FALSE   51d1d0f5c5bf9c328d79cbbd54a10bf99f73bcd3
```

And it can be `INSERT` into the History table:

```
INSERT INTO Table1_History(XID,FIELD1,FIELD2,DATECREATED,
                           METADATA$ACTION,METADATA$ISUPDATE)
SELECT XID,FIELD1,FIELD2,DATECREATED,
       METADATA$ACTION,UPPER(METADATA$ISUPDATE)
FROM Table1_Stream
WHERE METADATA$ACTION <> 'INSERT'
OR METADATA$ISUPDATE = 'TRUE'

SELECT * FROM Table1_History;

UID XID FIELD1  FIELD2  DATECREATED METADATA$ACTION METADATA$ISUPDATE   DATEINSERTED
1   1   1001    String1 2020-08-14 09:11:20.173 INSERT  TRUE    2020-08-14 09:13:41.474
2   1   101 String1 2020-08-14 09:11:20.173 DELETE  TRUE    2020-08-14 09:13:41.474
4   2   102 String2 2020-08-14 09:11:20.173 DELETE  FALSE   2020-08-14 09:17:37.694
```

And the Stream is NULL again:

```
SELECT * FROM Table1_Stream;

XID FIELD1  FIELD2  DATECREATED METADATA$ACTION METADATA$ISUPDATE   METADATA$ROW_ID
```

The one thing I don't understand is why the `UID` on `Table1_History` incremented to `4` instead of `3`, but that is a trivial problem.

This is how I will track all historical changes in Snowflake.

Comment: Hi - if you are OK with updating your history table every time you update your main table(s) then I'm not sure that using Streams adds anything (apart from complexity) to the process.

Why not just update the history table every time you update the main table(s)?

Comment: I like this because it distinctly separates the load/merge step from the data archiving step. Also, if someone does do ad-hoc Updates/Deletes they would get automatically captured.

Comment: "if someone does do ad-hoc Updates/Deletes they would get automatically captured". Surely they would only be captured (in the way you want, rather than in the way Streams are designed to work) if you inserted the data into the history table immediately after the ad-hoc update/delete? If it's ad hoc then how are you going to know to do this?
If you are allowing ad hoc changes I'm not clear how your approach is going to work anyway - as your approach relies on writing the stream data to your history table after every change i.e. hard-coding "INSERT INTO Table1_History..." after each DML

Comment: You can just prepend the `MERGE-SERT` with the `INSERT INTO HISTORY` code, so it will run twice. This means that the Stream captures two offsets:  the Delta between the Original table and the `MERGE-SERT`, then the Delta between the Table at end of the last `MERGE-SERT` and then before the `MERGE-SERT` is run again (though it will not capture if the same record is changed multiple times ad-hoc). In theory there should be no adhoc updates since all data should run through the `MERGE-SERT` procedure, but in practice sometimes you gotta make changes on the fly.

Comment: When you said "someone does do ad-hoc Updates/Deletes" I assumed that there were people other than yourself who might be executing these DML statements. If this is the case then aren't you still relying on them to know the process that you have outlined and to execute it correctly alongside the DML they are running? This doesn't seem like a robust solution to me but obviously up to you.
I would still go for the Change Tracking approach (see Update 2 in my answer) as this seems to be much simpler to implement and isn't reliant on people knowing they have to execute additional DML

Comment: Problem with the change tracking is it isn't exactly human readable. You can only look at changes from a delta at two specific points of time. I need to expose the change history to Operation-side people via third-party applications like Tableau. I will have change tracking on so I can query it directly in the DB as you suggested in your second update.

Answer (score 0):

Streams are not tables.

A stream only measures the delta since you last consumed (or initially defined) the stream. What you are currently seeing is you just keep overwriting data before you take another snapshot via the stream.  The initial insert values are what has changed since last time you captured the data.  By writing off the insert values to another table, a new snapshot is created from which to measure change from.

I suggest you create a table:
create table Table_history (...)

do your initial inserts to table1 and look at the stream:
(select * from Table1_History);

Now insert to your history table from the STREAM you defined:

insert into table_history (...)
select * from Table1_History ;

Check the stream again: select * from Table1_History
The data should be gone.  Nothing.

Then do the update:
UPDATE Table1 SET FIELD1 = 1001 WHERE XID = 1;

Check the stream again:
select * from Table1_History

Comment: Yes and that is the annoying thing that there is no standardized command to create a query-able table with changes tracked, and instead you have to insert the stream into another table after anytime that you might have changed the table. I think it would be nice if there was a magic command like MS SQL's `SYSTEM_VERSIONING` to track changes since this is fairly standard.